# draw a core-plot scatter-plot with a plot point gap

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-plot, scatter-plot

Im relativly new to core plot and I stuck at some point. 
I have a graph like this:
[image]

and want to draw the graph with no gap, like the red dotted line shows!
How would you do that without drawing a plot symbol at this point?
It also should be possible to connect the to points if the value in Y is different!
Has somebody dealed with that?
Thanks for any tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell the plot it has only 6 data points (`-numberOfRecordsForPlot:` returns 6).

```
Index   X     Y
-------------------
  0     0     6
  1     1     7
  2     3     7
  3     4     7
  4     5     6
  5     6     6
```

Comment: My example will draw the connecting line between the points at x = 1 and x = 3. What do you mean by "gap"?

Comment: if i use `-numberOfRecordsForPlot: return6;` i get only 6 entries. but i need to have all 7(days of a week)! is it possible to hide the plotSymbol on x = 2?

Comment: Implement the `-symbolForScatterPlot:recordIndex:` datasource method. Return a plot symbol (can be the same or different for each index, as desired) or `nil` for the points that you want to be drawn without a symbol.